# Queuing events with inotifywait

Tags: inotify, inotifywait, inotify-tools

Initialize source and destination directories.

```
srcdir=/user/user1/src
tagtdir=/user/user1/dest
```

I would like to get notified when a file is copied over into the srcdir and `-m` for continuous monitoring.

```
inotifywait -m -r -e close "$srcdir" | 

while read filename eventlist eventfile
```

Invoke my python script.

```
do 
    mv "$srcdir/$eventfile" "$tgtdir/$eventfile" && ./myscript.py "$eventfile" 
done
```

Unfortunately, my script that quite some time and if there are other files being copied over while `myscript.py` is being executed, I miss those events. Is it possible to queue up the events and process them later?

Another option is I will run `myscript.py` in background and that might solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/) instead; it runs as a persistent service and will remember the events that you missed.

There are a number of different ways that you might achieve your use-case, but probably the easiest is to set up a trigger and have watchman directly run your script as files change, or use the pywatchman client bindings to have a persistent python script run and subscribe to the events and take whatever action you'd like.